# Boost.Geometry buffer() algorithm: does it work for general case polygons

Tags: boost-geometry

I was looking here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/buffer/buffer.html
And saw this: "The current implemetation only enlarges a box, which is not defined by OGC. A next version of the library will contain a more complete implementation"

It looks like Boost Geometry is incapable of buffering an arbitrary polygon.  But various forum discussions refer to the buffer() algorithm like it actually works for the general case.  Which is correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Old answer: *The buffer() algorithm for the general case is in development, and can be used from the development version (Trunk). It generally works but not in all circumstances, and for all geometry types.*

New answer: **yes, it is possible**

Comment: This answer was 3.5 years ago - does anyone know if there is a release that includes this?

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/buffer/buffer_7_with_strategies.html